# Opening outlook with filled fields using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am trying to create a function to open a new Outlook message, but I would like the message to appear already with the recipient, subject fields.
So far what I have found is how to open a new Outlook window with the recipient, but I still can't get the subject to be displayed.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('mailto:email@domain.com', new=1)
```

Hope u can help me, ty.

Comment: It is important to open the mail window before sending it because many things will be added and modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailto` would work fine as long as you don't want HTML body or attachments. You can specify to/cc/bbc, subject, and body.

Something along the lines:

```
mailto:user1@domain.demo?subject=Test%20Subject&body=Test%20body&cc=user2@domain.demo&bcc=user3@domain.demo
```

And it will work under any OS and any email client.

Comment: Tysm it worked too!

Comment: Hi again, did u know if it's possible to do a line break inside the body? I have tried \n but it didn't work

Comment: Sure, the line break (0xD, 0xA) just needs to be url encoded - `line1%0D%0Aline2`

Comment: Tysm dude, i had not had time to try it, but today i saw your comment, i tried it and it worked, rlly tysm!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution using win32.com.client:

```
import win32.com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")  # Starts Outlook application
new_email = outlook.CreateItem(0)  # Creates new email item
new_email.To = "email@domain.com"  # Add recipients separated by comma or semicolon
new_email.Subject = "How to create new Outlook email in Python"  # Your email subject
new_email.Body = "This text will be the body of your new email"  # Your email body
new_email.Display(True)  # Displays the new email item
```

Comment: Tysm for answering, i tried to use it a moment ago but I got the error "No module named 'win32.com'", do you know the name of the library that must be installed to use it? I tried with win32/win32.com/win32.com.client but no such library appeared

Comment: Start a command line with Administrator rights and type the following `python -m pip install pywin32`, or alternatively, `pip install pywin32`.

Comment: Oh, i rlly found where the problem was, when importing the name is win32com.client not win32.com.client, now it worked, that was im looking for, tysm for helping!

Answer (score 0):

For using

```
import win32.com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")  # Starts Outlook application
... ...
```

You may need to include the following:

```
import pythoncom
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

Comment: It is the same as the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415475/332059